# my code not working for sending data to php

Tags: java, php, android, http

I used JSON for sending data to php from android. For this I used the code as below

```
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://futuretime.in/reg.php");

          httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

          JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();


          dataJson.put("password", password);
          dataJson.put("number", Integer.parseInt("5556"));

          StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dataJson.toString());
          httppost.setEntity(entity);
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
          text=response.toString();
```

when i excuted this i am getting a message like: org.apache.http.message.basichttpresponse 4fb06e5e

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

**Reference:** [EntityUtils Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should call-`response.getEntity().getContent()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this just pass your url in this method

```
public void getUrlData(String url)
{
    String result="";

    //Making HTTP request
    try
    {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);

        //defaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        url_error = 1;
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

And afterwards retrieve your data from String result, you can put result inside log to known the data

Comment: how should i pass data

Comment: You need to append your data to the url, in your case your sending password and number, so you should send like this 

    String basicUrl = "http://futuretime.in/reg.php";
    String url = basicUrl + "?<your password variable name in php file>=" + <your password> + " &<your number variable name in php file>=" + <your number>;
    getUrlData(url);